# v-img shows url instead of image in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify 2.3.10. The issue I am facing here is the v-img shows the image_url instead of the image. I tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53411531/12763413 but it didnt work for me. Please help me find the issue.

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
    <v-card flat>
     <v-data-table 
       :headers="headers"
       :items="users"
       v-model="users"
       :sort-by="['full_name']"
       class="elevation-1"
     >
     <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
       <td><v-img class="user-image" :src='props.item.image_url'/></td>
       <td class="full-name">{{ props.item.full_name }}</td>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>
   </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>



<script>

 export default {
  props: ['users'],
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: '', value: 'image_url', sortable: false },
      { text: 'Name', value: 'full_name', sortable: false  }
    ]
  })
 };
</script>
```

Comment: What version of Vuetify are you using? In current version there is no "items" slot - only "item". And you should wrap the content of that slot into `<tr></tr>`

Comment: @MichalLevý I am using vuetify version 2.3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not in `v-img` but in your usage of `v-data-table` - You are using non-existent slot `items` (should be `item`) so `v-data-table` is ignoring your slot content and rendering content of your `users` data as is...that's why you see url's instead of images

Also you should wrap the content `item` slot into `<tr></tr>`

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
    <v-card flat>
     <v-data-table 
       :headers="headers"
       :items="users"
       v-model="users"
       :sort-by="['full_name']"
       class="elevation-1"
     >
     <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
       <tr>
         <td><v-img class="user-image" :src='props.item.image_url'/></td>
         <td class="full-name">{{ props.item.full_name }}</td>
       </tr>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>
   </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: See the fixed template

Comment: Thankyou so much.