# Unable to display multiple image slider per page from a local folder not working with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to show multiple images in a slider per page using vuetify as well as Vue-awesome-swiper but doesnot work . Please help me.

```
     <v-sheet class="mx-auto" elevation="8" max-width="100%">
      <v-slide-group multiple show-arrows>
        <v-slide-item v-for="(n, i) in images" :key="i" v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">
          <v-img :src="n.src" class="ma-4" height="250" width="300"/>
     
        </v-slide-item>
      </v-slide-group>
    </v-sheet>
```

```
  data: () => ({
     images: [
      { alt: "A kitten", src: "require(`@/assets/images/workplan.jpg`)" },
      { alt: "A kitten", src: "require(`@/assets/images/workplan.jpg`)" },
      { alt: "A kitten", src: "require(`@/assets/images/workplan.jpg`)" },    
      { alt: "A kitten", src: "require(`@/assets/images/workplan.jpg`)" }
    ]
  }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've noticed in your code:

1. It should be `:src="n.src"` and not `@src="{{ n.src }}"`. `@` is short for `v-on` whereas `:` is short for `v-bind`. What we need is `v-bind:src` and there is no such thing as `v-on:src` as far as I know.
2. Provide a proper `:key` to each `<v-slide-item/>`. [Avoid using non-primitive value for key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420082/vue-warn-avoid-using-non-primitive-value-as-key-use-string-number-value-inst).
3. Use Vuetify's `<v-img/>` component over `<img/>` tags.

[image]

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-napier-ttibk?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

Comment: I'm unable to show other images in slider. Is it beacuase of image size? @Blackraspberryyy

Comment: It might be the case. Try wrapping the image in a div or a v-card with fixed width similar to the [vuetify's example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups/#multiple)

Comment: I used v-slide-group  and compressed image upto 8kb still unable to display image @Blackraspberryyy

Comment: If your image comes from a local directory, you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53411531/9183405). Also, I suggest to have a fixed width to your `<v-img/>` by using the [width attribute](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#api). I've updated my codesandbox to have a width attribute to v-img

Comment: When I changes code like above, still its not working. @Blackraspberryyy

Comment: You shouldn't make the `src` a string. It should be something like this: `src: require('@/assets/images/workplan.jpg')`. Check my updated codesandbox that uses require().